# In web2py, how to find a row from rows given its id?

Tags: web2py

I have

```
query= (db.mytable.ref_other_table==other_table_id)
rows=db(query).select()
```

How can I find a row in rows, knowing the records id, for instance, I can do

```
ix=0
while rows[ix].id != id:
    ix+=1
```

but is this the most efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
row = rows.find(lambda r: r.id == some_id)
```

However, depending on how many records are in `rows`, it could actually be faster to just retrieve the record directly from the database:

```
row = db.mytable(some_id)
```